# Noise in my handsfree

Tags: sound-card, headphones, headphone-jack

I have a wired handsfree (It's new). When I connect it to my laptop, I hear some noise like the sound of wind. It works with my phone without any problem also my other handsfree work with my laptop without any problem.
My handsfree is Samsung galaxy A7 handsfree and my laptop works with Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

Please try and check some of these steps. [Link to guide](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-headphone-not-working-in-windows-10/)

The handfree is connected via wireless connection (Typically bluetooth), and therefore doesn't get affected by the jack connection.

Please also try with another jack headset, to troubleshoot if it's the new headset or it's the jack-port.

Comment: It's not wireless. I didn't understand the rest.

Comment: I assumed as it's handfree (not a word I'm used to when it comes to headsets), that it was a wireless. - Please try and follow the linked guide, and see if that helps. It might just be an issue in the windows sound configuration.

Comment: Some of them are related to wireless devices. I did those related to my device (I updated driver and set it as default).

Comment: If you try connecting another headset (not wireless) will that also have noise?

Comment: no, only one of them.